# Android: option menu + Action Bar

Tags: android, menu

How can i create this type of sub menu in grid with icon and title.

[image]

Comment: Are you using Actionbar Sherlock?

Comment: yes m using actionbar with sherlock libs

Comment: sub menu option list iiw working but i want grid with icon and title

Answer (score 0):

You should use Quick action menu which is a pop-up-like component which displays actions that can be performed on an object. It can be also used to display custom messages like a tooltip pop-up anchored to a certain component of your screen.

Take look at [QuickActionMenu](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D)

[QuickAction Tutorial](http://www.chupamobile.com/tutorial/details/63/Quick+Actions+-+Tutorial/)

Comment: my question is grid view in sub menu.

Comment: there is no need to use gridview you can set it as horizontally and vertically both way. Just check out the demo and try out.

Comment: my frnd my req is grid view sub menu. i don't want other type of menu.

Answer (score 0):

I've built my own menu (attachments) ,like whatsapps

1. build xml file that contains framelayout so the attachment can be
   shown in front of other layouts.    The xml contains buttons for
   each attachment type.
2. add attach button / add on menu button listener (in my case).
3. add boolean that changes each time you
   press the attach button in order to open/close.

here is my code as an example:

XML file with the images, names and colors:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="263dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#464646"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#303030"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/attach_gallery"
                android:text="Gallery"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#303030"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/attach_camera_picture"
                android:text="Photo"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#303030"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/attach_camera_video"
                android:text="Video"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#303030"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/attach_voice"
                android:text="Audio"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#303030"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/attach_location"
                android:text="Location"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#303030"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/attach_contacts"
                android:text="Contact"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

My Activity:

```
// attachment layout appear only on menu click
        attachLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.attachLayout);
        attachLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.attach_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (isAttachGridVisible)
            attachLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        else{
            attachLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        isAttachGridVisible = !isAttachGridVisible;

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

isAttachGridVisible  is a boolean.

attach_menu xml menu file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/attachments"
        android:icon="@drawable/attachwhatsapp"
        android:orderInCategory="11111"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="">

    </item>
</menu>
```

Good Luck